# get <button> value in PHP

Tags: php, html, button

I came across a situation where I have to use a simple button instead of a submit button. Is it possible to get the button value or check if it is 'isset' with PHP?

Normally with submit buttons I'd do this:

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
```

This is what my button looks like:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit();" value="Pay with Cash" name="book_pay_on_day" style="width:170px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" class="btn-stripe"></button>
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is there even a parent `<form>` around the `<button>`? Show us your full code.

Comment: "this.form.submit" what form ??

Comment: Like @Dagon said, `this.form.submit` won't work. `onclick` attributes will refer to `window` in their `this` keyword. So, `this.form === window.form` in this situation. Unless you defined `var form` somewhere, this will not work. **EDIT**: This is wrong, nevermind. See Quentin's comment.

Comment: @Dagon — `this` will be a reference to the button, the `form` property of the button will be the form to which the button belongs.

Comment: @Joeytje50 — Wrong. `this` will be the button. You might be being confused by `onclick="something()"` and `function something() { this.etc }` which is because of the way `something` is called, not the way `onclick` is called.

Comment: @Quentin oh, yes that is probably it.

Comment: @Quentin, my point was there is no form at all here.

Comment: It worked guys, I just used onclick to add a value to a hidden field. Thx

Comment: @user3693102 — 
Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You want `$_POST['book_pay_on_day']`. The index in `$_POST` will always be the *name* of the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Only a submit button used to submit a form will send its value to the server.

You could write JavaScript to get the value of the button and add a hidden input to the form using DOM before calling the submit method, but you'd be better off switching out to a submit button and not using JS at all.

Just remove the `type` attribute (`submit` is the default value) and the `onclick`.

```
<button value="Pay with Cash" name="book_pay_on_day" style="width:170px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;" class="btn-stripe"></button>
```

You'll then need to look for the right name:

```
$_POST['book_pay_on_day']
```

Comment: I just used JS... why is it bad? See I cannot use a submit button because there's another button (stripe.js) which is interfering with other submit buttons.

Comment: Using JavaScript to submit the form is more complicated, more likely to go wrong, and doesn't do what you want.